# View post google plus on my app

Tags: android, google-plus

I created an android application connected to google plus, I wanted to know if it was possible to see the posts of the connected user and his friends.

For Example:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not a public API for a users home stream. There is an [open feature](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=25) request you can star.

Comment: If I wanted to see only posts the user logged?

Comment: What do you mean by logged? What kind of posts?

Comment: I wanted to know if it was possible to see the posts of the connected user

Comment: You can get public posts of any specific user using [activities.list](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list).